How to fix worker runtime metadata for Azure .net8 isolated worker model functions?
I have upgraded a .net6 Azure function (using an App Service plan, not Consumption) to an isolated .net8 function. All my assemblies have <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
The function project has also
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>

and also
  <ItemGroup>
        <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>

( I have no idea what it's doing but it was given in a Microsoft upgrade article).
When deploying, the pipeline sets the following values:
"FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION": "~4",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
"WEBSITE_USE_PLACEHOLDER_DOTNETISOLATED": 1,
"WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE": 1,

My functions seem fine, scheduled functions are triggered, and service bus messages go through.
Still, Azure shows the warning:
The 'FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME' is set to 'dotnet-isolated', which does not match the worker runtime metadata found in the deployed function app artifacts. The deployed artifacts are for 'dotnet'. See https://aka.ms/functions-invalid-worker-runtime for more information. The application will continue to run but may throw an exception in the future.

I redeployed and restarted the function multiple times during the last two days, but the message did not go away.
I started hunting for the mysterious "worker runtime metadata" but could not find any useful information. Then I looked inside the artifact zip that is built by the pipeline and searched for "dotnet" text inside. The only text files mentioning it are worker.config.json with:
{
  "description": {
    "language": "dotnet-isolated",
    "extensions": [ ".dll" ],
    "defaultExecutablePath": "dotnet",
    "defaultWorkerPath": "MyNamespace.Function.dll",
    "workerIndexing": "true",
    "canUsePlaceholder": true
  }
}

and functions.metadata, which has "language": "dotnet-isolated" for all of the functions. So, no mention of "dotnet" without "isolated".
Function settings in Azure look good after deployment: Runtime version ~4, .NET Version is .NET 8 Isolated.
When I look at the individual functions themselves in Azure and try to edit them, I get this warning:
Editing .NET isolated Function Apps is not supported in the Azure portal. Use your local development environment to edit this Function App.

This indicates that the functions are correct with the language "dotnet-isolated".
What am I missing here? Where is this mysterious "worker runtime metadata" that Azure warns about?

I don't think you are missing anything at all. The warning indicates, that the deployed version is a in-process function which is different than the version you are deploying. Which is expected after migrating an existing function.
You can check in the Portal which language is used. And update it to dotnet-isolated. As far as I know, this should resolve the warning.

If you are using ARM Templates, ensure you set properties.siteConfig.netFrameworkVersion to "v8.0"
If you go to https://resources.azure.com/, you should be able to see the metadata of the App Service, or if you look into the audit logs after applying the settings over the portal (from above). But those are set indirectly by deploying the first time or by updating the language

Thanks, function settings in Azure looked good immediately after deployment, and they remain Runtime version = ~4, .NET Version = .NET 8 Isolated. I checked the metadata json in the resources but it does not have any values mentioning dotnet or isolated. I may hope it's some kind of a caching glitch in Azure and might resolve itself in a few days. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.
